# Using regex to validate a field

Tags: java, android, regex, validation

Sorry for being new to programming. Apparently I'm expected to know everything about the topic before posting here. I've only been doing this 3 weeks, learning as I go.

I've got a field limited to 5 characters I'm trying to validate. The first character must be a letter, and the following 4 characters must be numbers. Regex is like Greek to me at this point, so I'm having trouble. I've been able to get the first character validated, but I'm stumped on the remaining 4. Here's my code:

```
if (carID.substring(0, 1).matches("[0-9]")) {
    showDataFormatError();
    break;
} else {
    if (carID.substring(1, 5).matches("[a-zA-Z]")) {
    showDataFormatError();
    break;
    }
}
```

---

Updating to demonstrate my horrible coding at this point.

```
            if (carID.length() < 5) {
                showDataLengthError();
                break;
            } else {
                if (carID.matches("^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}$")) {
                    showDataFormatError();
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (carYearString.length() < 0) {
                        showDateLengthError();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        try {
                            int carYear = Integer.parseInt(carYearString);
                            int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(
                                    Calendar.YEAR);

// etc.
```

Comment: Try `carID.matches("^[A-Za-z]\\d{4}$")`.

Comment: You can learn basics of regex from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: @falsetru doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: @geek_sauce, See http://ideone.com/RxXXsh

Comment: @falsetru I think I'm in over my head on this one.

Comment: You are calling `showDataFormatError()` when the data is correct. You need `if (!carID.matches ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
boolean valid = carID.matches("^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}$");
```

And see [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

EDIT thanks to the down voter I spotted and fixed the error.

Comment: Can you give an example? `
        String carID = "a1234";
        boolean valid = carID.matches("^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}$");
        System.out.println("carID "+valid);
` outputs `
    carID true
`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure the entire string is that format, use:

```
^[a-zA-Z]\d{4}$
```

this will help you and for tutorial you should have to go through this link

[Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like..

```
\pL       Matches Any kind of letter from any language.
\pN{4}    Matches Any kind of numeric character in any script. (4 times) greedy.
```

...

```
if (carID.length() > 5) throw IllegalArgumentException();

if (carID.matches("^\pL\pN{4}$")){
  return true;
} else {
  return false;

  ...
}
```